# Use a preset vim colorscheme in bash (Mac OSX)

Tags: bash, vim

I'm trying to use the desert colorscheme for vim in bash on my Mac OS X.  I changed my .vimrc file to include the line 
 `colorscheme desert`

There was no .vim directory in my home directory, so i made one and made a colors directory inside that.  Then I downloaded desert.vim and put it in the colors directory.  The colorscheme is still not working.  Any experienced vimmers know what I might have missed?

Comment: what happens if you run vim and then say `:colorscheme desert`

Comment: Do you have any colors at all? `:syntax on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a VIM varible for it to work. Add this line to your .vimrc:

```
let $VIM ='~/.vim/'
```

In fact this line tells vim to check for folder "~/.vim/" to load plugins, colors, syntaxes, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

This should work, or there is an important piece of information missing. Note that the desert colorscheme comes with the vim provided by OS X so you shouldn't even need to install it.